# Error while ploting multiple geopandas (ArcMap and KML) in the same projection?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, plot

I seek help on:

- Finding possible errors on projections management
- Guiding me on which should be the best way to know which "labels - colors" are within the path line  (not exposed here)

--

Source 1: Geopandas imported from ArcMap in .shp format - It contains all shapes (4k) and is used as the basic map. It's very populated in terms of ArcMap columns and attributes

Source 2: Geopandas imported from KML coordinates in .csv format - It's a ROV path in UTM 31N zone.

## Steps done:

Import and plot ArcMap representation in GeoPandas. Done! "The same" as ArcMap
[image: Source 1]

Import and plot KML path in GeoPandas. Done!

[image: Source 2]

Make them work in the same CRS

```
# print(gdf.crs) == > epsg:32631

# Source 2 is directly readed from CSV. Need to assign geocode.
# For a non GIS guy, makes sense to apply || epsg: 32631 or 25831

# print(track.crs) == > 32633   Value determined automatically. As the input for source 2 is just KML coordinates
track = track.to_crs(gdf.crs)


print(gdf.crs)     # After conversion, both are the same: epsg:32631 
print(track.crs)

# Follow the convention of plotting both geoPandas by sharing an axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
gdf.plot(ax=axes, color=gdf['Color'])
track.plot(ax=axes)
```

## Incorrect output:

Can you see the miniature of SOURCE 1?

[image]

I assume this point is my KML path:

[image]

## What I expected

(picture from ArcMap):

[image]

Comment: Plot the converted gpd and check if reference system is the same as that of source1. crs might have changed but not the coordinates.

Comment: I'm struggling on these.... it seems it's not been converted. I assumed it was as easy as: `track = track.to_crs(gdf.crs)` [....]

Answer (score 0):

The only workarround I found was to load the KML to `ArcGIS`, and then, download the tracks of my interest in `.shp` format.

Then, both CRS of boths Shapes that were perfectly plotted in `ArcGIS`, were also properly plotted in `Python`